# client-side validation mvc 2 number wrong required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 project with this model:

```
    [DisplayName("Valor(%)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es requerido")]
    public decimal HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR1  { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Valor(%)")]
    public decimal HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR2 { get; set; }
```

View:

```
Html.EnableClientValidation();
```

And the output client-side validation:

```
   {
        "FieldName": "HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR1",
        "ReplaceValidationMessageContents": true,
        "ValidationMessageId": "HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR1_validationMessage",
        "ValidationRules": [
            {
                "ErrorMessage": "Este dato es requerido",
                "ValidationParameters": {},
                "ValidationType": "required"
            },
            {
                "ErrorMessage": "The field Valor(%) must be a number.",
                "ValidationParameters": {},
                "ValidationType": "number"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "FieldName": "HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR2",
        "ReplaceValidationMessageContents": true,
        "ValidationMessageId": "HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR2_validationMessage",
        "ValidationRules": [
            {
                "ErrorMessage": "The Valor(%) field is required.",
                "ValidationParameters": {},
                "ValidationType": "required"
            },
            {
                "ErrorMessage": "The field Valor(%) must be a number.",
                "ValidationParameters": {},
                "ValidationType": "number"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Why decimal fields add a default required attribute?
I need remove required validationtype.

Answer (score 0):

Your decimals need to be nullable, otherwise MVC will make them required;

```
[DisplayName("Valor(%)")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es requerido")]
public decimal? HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR1  { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Valor(%)")]
public decimal? HOJ_ATI_CONT_SAPO_VALOR2 { get; set; }
```

I believe this is because there is no such thing as an empty decimal - if the decimal wasn't set, then it would be stored as '0'.  This is more clear if you try to pass a blank field to a decimal parameter on an MVC action method.